# ¿Como imprimir un arreglo con un foreach en CODEIGNITER?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

En el **modelo de BD** hace bien la consulta, en el **Controller**  se manda correctamente la informacion a la view pero **en la View** no se como imprimir la matriz en un foreach.**La unica forma que e logrado imprimir el arreglo es**  con lo siguiente:

```
<?php 
     print_r($mostrar2);
?>
```

y me arroja el la vista la siguiente informacion:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [nombre] => Cinema [nombre_comando] =>
>   systemctl disable locura [valor] => 12 ) [1] => Array ( [nombre] =>
>   Cinema [nombre_comando] => systemctl disable locura [valor] => enable
>   ) [2] => Array ( [nombre] => Cinema [nombre_comando] => systemctl
>   disable locura [valor] => sas ) [3] => Array ( [nombre] => Cinema
>   [nombre_comando] => systemctl disable locura [valor] => enable ) [4]
>   => Array ( [nombre] => Cinema [nombre_comando] => systemctl disable locura [valor] => sas ) [5] => Array ( [nombre] => Cinema
>   [nombre_comando] => systemctl disable locura [valor] => false ) [6] =>
>   Array ( [nombre] => Cinema [nombre_comando] => systemctl disable
>   locura [valor] => false ) [7] => Array ( [nombre] => Farmacias AS
>   [nombre_comando] => systemctl disable locura [valor] => false ) [8] =>
>   Array ( [nombre] => Farmacias AS [nombre_comando] => systemctl disable
>   locura [valor] => sas ) [9] => Array ( [nombre] => Farmacias AS
>   [nombre_comando] => systemctl disable BBB [valor] => ) [10] => Array (
>   [nombre] => Farmacias AS [nombre_comando] => systemctl disable vsftpd
>   [valor] => sad ) [11] => Array ( [nombre] => iQOS [nombre_comando] =>
>   systemctl prueba solucion escritura [valor] => false ) [12] => Array (
>   [nombre] => local [nombre_comando] => systemctl disable BBB [valor] =>
>   sas ) [13] => Array ( [nombre] => local [nombre_comando] => systemctl
>   disable locura [valor] => false ) [14] => Array ( [nombre] => local
>   [nombre_comando] => systemctl disable locura [valor] => )

necesito que únicamente me muestre estos valores

**Cinema, systemctl disable locura,  12**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He traducido tu array de objetos a php, ya que pides que se haga en php, faltan datos a los que muestras pero espero te pueda ayudar.

```
$datos = [
    ['nombre'=> 'Cinema', 'nombre_comando'=> 'systemctl disable locura', 'valor'=> '12'],
    ['nombre'=> 'Cinema', 'nombre_comando'=> 'systemctl disable locura', 'valor'=> 'enable'],
    ['nombre'=> 'Cinema', 'nombre_comando'=> 'systemctl disable locura', 'valor'=> 'sas'],
    ['nombre'=> 'Cinema', 'nombre_comando'=> 'systemctl disable locura', 'valor'=> 'enable'],
    ['nombre'=> 'Cinema', 'nombre_comando'=> 'systemctl disable locura', 'valor'=> 'false'],
    ['nombre'=> 'Cinema', 'nombre_comando'=> 'systemctl disable locura', 'valor'=> 'sad']];
```

Recorremos el arreglo correspondiente.

```
foreach($datos as $key){
   echo $key['nombre'].', '.$key['nombre_comando'].', '.$key['valor'].'<br>';
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias me fue de utilidad tu información  saludos!!!